# How to get list of sequence names in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I want to get the list of sequence names in Postgres.

In Oracle, I can use:

```
select sequence_name 
from user_sequences
```

But in Postgres when I use that statement it always throws the error: **not found user_sequences**.

How can I do this in Postgres?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`SELECT c.relname FROM pg_class c WHERE c.relkind = 'S';`
Or trying running psql as `psql -U username -E` followed by `\ds`. This will show you the query that was been used to generate the result as well.

Comment: I want to get this like the Oracle,through sql statement to select the sequence name.

Comment: About this question in sqlsever,How can I do it ?"SELECT * FROM SYS.SEQUENCES" can not get anything .

Comment: @liu246437 I am not too sure about this as I have not use sqlserver before. Maybe you can post a new question with the relevant tags so that the other professionals can help you better.

Comment: @liu246437 Note that this will show sequences _accessible_ to the current user, not the ones **owned** by the current user (which is what `user_sequences` in Oracle does)

Answer (score 34):

You can use:

```
select sequence_schema, sequence_name
from information_schema.sequences;
```

That will return a list of sequences *accessible* to the current user, not the ones **owned** by him.

If you want to list sequences **owned** by the current user you need to join `pg_class`, `pg_namespace` and `pg_user`:

```
select n.nspname as sequence_schema, 
       c.relname as sequence_name,
       u.usename as owner
from pg_class c 
  join pg_namespace n on n.oid = c.relnamespace
  join pg_user u on u.usesysid = c.relowner
where c.relkind = 'S'
  and u.usename = current_user;
```

In Postgres a user can own objects (e.g. sequences) in multiple schemas, not just "his own", so you also need to check in which schema the sequence is created.

More details in the manual:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-sequences.html
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-class.html