# How to get sequence name list in sqlserver?

Tags: sql-server

[How to get list of sequence names in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38194364/how-to-get-sequence-name-list-in-postgresql)

Today,I asked how to get the sequence name list in the postgresql,Thanks to DunnoHowToCode provides the answer for me.

Now,the same question I meet in sqlsever.I through

```
SELECT * FROM sys.SEQUENCES
```

to get it,but anything I can't get.I want to get the sequence name list by sql statement in sqlsever.How can I do it?

Comment: Do you have any `Sequence` created in `SQL SERVER`

Comment: `SELECT name FROM sys.SEQUENCES` will return the names of all sequence objects created in your database.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you have with `SELECT * FROM sys.SEQUENCES`

Comment: @ZoharPeled - He already wrote that query didn't find anything

Comment: If the query doesn't return anything, there is no sequence to return. Are you looking in the correct database? Do you have permission to use the sequence ?

Comment: @Prdp Yeah, I've seen that. I suspect Panagiotis Kanavos is correct, and the execution of the query was on the wrong database.

Comment: @ZoharPeled - yep, even I feel the same

Comment: Thanks to everyone,I created sequence,but not return anything,so does errors.I don't think the database is wrong,because I creat the sequence and test it.It succeed.

Comment: @liu246437 `sys.sequences` isn't broken. Post your code, including the `USE [somedb]` statement that actually changes databases and the code that *creates* the sequence. I'd guess you are running your query in `master` but created the sequence in a different database. To avoid confusion, include the database name in the query, ie `select * from mydb.sys.sequences`

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos Thanks,I am not select the database.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`sys.sequences` isn't broken. Your query will return all the sequences in a database as long as there *are* any sequences in that database. If you don't get any results, it means that there aren't any sequences. Make sure you execute the query in the correct database. Better yet, include the database name in the query, ie:

```
select * from mydb.sys.sequences
```

Answer (score 5):

You can view them in SSMS, in the Object Explorer:

[image]